# XmlDocument type not found even though I've referenced System.XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, reference, namespaces

I've referenced System.Xml:

```
using System.Xml;
```

Then in this line:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
```

I get:

> The type or namespace name
>   'XmlDocument' could not be found

What could there possibly be wrong ?

Info:

.NET 3.5, C#, triple checked that it's referenced and used in the same document, been able to use similar and even child libraries (System.Linq;System.Xml.Linq;System.Xml.XPath; System.Xml;)

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project from scratch?  I can't seem to get this to happen and wonder if there's some version mismatch or project corruption going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your project references the System.Xml.dll *assembly*.  It's possible that you're referencing a different assembly that contains other System.Xml.* classes and that might be why you're seeing the System.Xml namespace but without the classes you need.

If you already have this reference, try removing and re-adding it and see if that irons out some weird VS glitch.

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps working inside a SilverLight project?

Only time I have experienced this was when starting out in SilverLight, I did not realise that not all of the System.XML was in the Silverlight CLR version. I used System.Linq.XML instead.

Comment: Nope it isnt. Surprisingly enough it's a winforms c# .net 3.5 project =(

Answer (score 3):

I know that the question is already answered, but I want to add the solution for the very similar problem that I had, which might help others:

In my case it was a simple misspelling, well, not even that, it was an uppercase-lowercase-fault:
**There are 2 classes: `XMLDocument` (from msxml.h) and `XmlDocument` (from System.Xml).**
  Make sure that you're not mixing them up! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but the problem persists nowadays.
I'm on a Xamarin.Forms project and the PCL project targets a profile (Profile111) that doesn't support XmlDocument. **I had to use System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.**
My projects targets WindowsPhone and XmlDocument doesn't exist on this target.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, you need to include the .NET Standard [package from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/). You can also just include the System.Xml.XmlDocument [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/) directly if that's all you need.