# XmlDocument does not exist in current context

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reference, windows

I referenced System.Xml in my code, but XmlDocument still does not show up. Whenever I try to use it, it tells me:

```
Error: The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found (are you missing a
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607852/xmldocument-type-not-found-even-though-ive-referenced-system-xml) that seemed pretty helpful; unfortunately, I am using a Windows Apps template, and it does not allow me to remove or add references, and I am sure that I am not using Silverlight. I am using Visual Studio 2013, with .NET 4.5. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am trying to make a background task. This is how I am using it:

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
```

Comment: Please add more reference code. How do you implement `'XmlDocument'` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it: the library had been changed or something, so XmlDocument is no longer under System.Xml.
It is now under Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.

This worked:

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
```